# How to style 2 vertical jQuery UI Slider handles?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have 2 vertical jQuery UI sliders that offer different functionality to the user. I would like to have different coloured handles on both of them. How do I keep them unique? Currently, I am using the following in my CSS to change the style, but it's being applied to both of them:

```
.ui-slider-vertical .ui-slider-handle {
     /*CSS goes here*/
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sliders keep their `ID` when initialized..  So just give each of your sliders a unique id and then apply the `css` to each one.

```
#slider-vertical .ui-slider-handle {
    background:none!important;
    background-color:blue!important;
}

#slider-vertical2 .ui-slider-handle {
    background:none!important;
    background-color:red!important;
}
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/NYYwh/